# laravel　500エラーになる

Tags: php, laravel

windowsのコマンドプロンプトで、`php artisan serve`と書いて実行すると`Laravel development server started:http://・・・` と表示され、そのURLをブラウザで開くと500エラーが出ます。

プロジェクトは、コマンドプロンプト上でただ`laravel new プロジェクト名`と打ち、プロジェクト内に入って`composer update`を行ったあとに、`php artisan serve`を打ったので中身を私は特に触っていません。

解決策を教えてくださると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php artisan serveではデフォルトでは8000ポートを使用していたかと思いますが、そのポートを既に別のプロセスが使用しているということはないでしょうか？
下記コマンドで確認ください。また、storage/logsディレクトリにログが出力されていると思うので、それも確認ください。

```
netstat -ano
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！そちらのコマンドを入力したのですが、別で8000が使用していることはなさそうでした。ログの確認も行ったのですがログは特に記述されていませんでした…プロジェクトを作りなおしてみようと思います。ありがとうございました。